# How to execute YAML program within a python program and how can i parse the output of YAML into a csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

If I have `script1.yaml` and `script2.py`,
I can execute:

```
pyresttest script1.yaml para1 para2
```

in script2 using below code.
I need to parse the output for `script1.yaml` in a csv/html

```
import os
os.system("pyresttest script1.yaml para1 para2")
```

using python how can I parse the output of

```
pyresttest script1.yaml para1 para2
```

into a CSV/HTML?

Comment: make pyresttest.py as executable then copy to /usr/bin

Comment: Please do *not* copy anything to `/usr/bin`, basically ever.

Comment: hi @Dietrich Epp can you explain why.

Comment: @Ravi Teja If he is right add pyresttest path in environment variable 'path'

Comment: @Arun: The directory `/usr/bin` is for programs that are part of your system, only your operating system (package manager) should ever install programs there.  It is almost never a good idea to put a program there yourself.  It's also completely unnecessary in this case.  You don't have to install a program globally just to run it.  You can either run it by specifying its path or you can add it to `PATH`.

Comment: @Arun: On macOS, it's even been locked down so you *can't* copy a file to `/usr/bin`, *even if you are root.*